# Emacs 24.3 on Windows, how to upgrade to the most recent version?

Tags: windows, emacs, upgrade

I'm a new Emacs user and I'm using Emacs 24.3 on Windows. I've already installed and configured some packages. Now I want to upgrade to 24.4, since I need some of the new features. How can I do that? Simply back up `.emacs.d` and remove everything in the `emacs` folder, then download and unpack emacs 24.4 and recover `.emacs.d`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to touch `~/.emacs.d`.  Just install (aka unpack) Emacs-24.4 and (if you want) delete the Emacs-24.3 install.

Comment: You mean just extract it on top of the existing installation (e.g. `c:\emacs`) and overwrite everything? Sounds easy. But I don't think there's an `i386` version of 24.4 yet?

Comment: Extracting on-top of the other might lead to weird results, so I'd extract it elsewhere and just use that new location (which also lets you keep the old one, so you can transition more progressively).  Of course you can also begin by deleting/moving the old one and then unpack the new one where the old one was.

Comment: There's an i686 version for Windows in https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/.  I highly doubt that your machine is so old that you need an i386 version (even my venerable Thinkpad X30 is "young enough").

Comment: Thanks, advice on installation is appreciated. I take your point on i386 but 24.3 was just labelled `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip` while this latest one is `emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip`. Does that mean that it includes MinGW? I would prefer not to install anything additional over and above Emacs - it's just more to have to maintain and avoid breaking.

Comment: No, the change of name is likely just an artifact of the fact that it's built by someone else.